# Not able to disable zoom with meta tag

Tags: html, css

When i try to disable zoom with a meta tag like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

The only result i get is that the page starts zoomed really in and all the divs that are sized after %, get way to small because the page automaticly zooms out again and I am able to zoom anyway. So this method did not work for me at all. My question is there any other method or is there something wrong with the current method?

Comment: What device did you test this on?

Comment: *" because the page automaticly zooms out again"* - Any Javascript in your page which changes styles?

Comment: I tested it on my iphone in safari, the same problem occurs in google chrome inspector when it is in mobile mode. @KobyDouek

Comment: I do change the opacity and visibility of some elements trough javascript. @KobyDouek

Comment: ...still open? Did You tried by adding `shrink-to-fit=no` to the viewport`meta tag?

Answer (score 0):

This works IOS 10

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
    event = event.originalEvent || event;
    if (event.scale !== 1) {
       event.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

Or

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=480, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0,target-densitydpi=device-dpi, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: This made accidental zoom not happen, but i can still zoom if i really try.

Comment: The other suggestion did the same as Chandra Kumar's answer

Comment: try this <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0,target-densitydpi=device-dpi, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: This made zoom disabled but it starts the page way to zoomed in so the divs get weird

Answer (score 0):

Is there any Javascript on your page which puts focus on a form field when the page loads? That would cause zooming on an iPhone, especially if the font size of the field is less than 16px.